# ASP.NET Client side validation and Post back

Tags: asp.net, validation, client-side

I have an aspx page in which i have 3 asp.net text boxes and 1 asp.net button control.I want to do a client side validation before the post back happens when i click on the button . ie ; If the the page passes the validation check,then only i need to invoke the server side button click event.Can any one help me  ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define JS function:

```
function validate(){
    //perform some validation
    return $("#myTextbox").val()=="";
}
```

call it on button control onclick event="return DoValidation();"

If JS function will return false, postback will be canceled.

Comment: Then where i should mention the Server side event ?

Comment: Mention the server side OnClick and use OnClientClick to register client side javascript to the event.

Comment: @7alwagy thx for your reply, i couldn't check stackoverflow faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate with ASP.net validation, need to register your Javascript validator using **RegisterValidator** declaration.

Don't forget to valiate on the server-side too, as Javascript may be disabled.